# MVVM Caliburn.micro comboboxes Country-City doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, caliburn.micro

I'm using MVVM with Caliburn.Micro and i have a problem.
So i have 2 comboboxes on view. First is to represent a list of countries and second of citites. I want the cities list to update whenever the country in the first list is changed, with corresponding list of cities. My problem is that cities list doesn't update.
Here is my code:

```
public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    Company company = new Company();
    List<string> countries = new List<string> {"USA","Germany" };
    public string Name
    {
        get { return company.name; }
        set { company.name = value;
        }
    }
    public List<string> Countries
    {
        get { return countries; }
        set {
            company.country = ToString();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Countries);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Cities);
        }
    }
    public List<string> Cities
    {
        get {
            switch (company.country)
            {
                case "USA": return new List<string> { "New York", "Los Angeles" };  
                case "Germany": return new List<string> { "Hamburg", "Berlin" };
                default: return new List<string> { "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT" };

            }
            }
        set { company.city = value.ToString();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Cities);
        }
    }

}
```

Now the cities list remain with default members ( DEFAULT, DEFAULT). The view contains only 2 comboboxes with corresponding names:

```
<Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Countries" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="Cities" />
</Grid>
```

Some suggestions ? 
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `SelectedItem` property of the country `ComboBox` to a source property of the view model:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Countries" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}" />
<ComboBox x:Name="Cities" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" />
```

...and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Cities` property in the setter of this one:

```
public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    Company company = new Company();
    List<string> countries = new List<string> { "USA", "Germany" };
    public string SelectedCountry
    {
        get { return company.country; }
        set
        {
            company.country = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedCountry);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Cities);
        }
    }
    public List<string> Countries
    {
        get { return countries; }
        set
        {
            countries = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Countries);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Cities);
        }
    }
    public List<string> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            switch (company.country)
            {
                case "USA": return new List<string> { "New York", "Los Angeles" };
                case "Germany": return new List<string> { "Hamburg", "Berlin" };
                default: return new List<string> { "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT" };

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to the following blog post for a complete example and more information about how to implement this kind of cascading `ComboBoxes`: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/17/cascading-comboboxes-in-wpf-using-mvvm/